# Can Google GDK Glass Development Kit used with Vuzix glasses?

Tags: android, google-gdk, aero-glass

I have a question regarding which glasses / devices the Google Glass Development Kit supports? 
For our university project we just have the vuzix m100 running on andorid 4.0.3. I cant find a answer on the web, if it is possible to develop with the GDK for vuzix m100 Glass too?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> which glasses / devices the Google Glass Development Kit supports?

It supports Google Glass.

> For our university project we just have the vuzix m100 running on andorid 4.0.3

You need to purchase an SDK for that, based on what [Vusix's developer site](http://developer.vuzix.com/) indicates. Hopefully whoever bought your Vusix M100 already purchased the SDK, in which case you would use that.

Comment: FIY Vuzix M100 is running Android 4.x and you can just enable developer mode to start building apps.