# develop for Vuzix M100 smart glasses

Tags: android-studio, google-glass, google-gdk, vuzix, vuzixm100

I am developing for Google glass using Glass Development Kit + android studio. I am unable to run this apk file on Vuzix M100 smart glasses. So for this problem I checked its developer [site](http://www.vuzix.com/developer/) .This website says that "We need to use eclipse IDE along with vuzix sdk to develop for same."

Please suggest me on below mentioned points :

- So it will cause double work for me. Any body knows any solution to this problem ?
- Can I upgrade Vuzix Smart phone OS to run API level 19 ?
- How can I make this apk generated using GDK to run on Vuzix M100 Smart Glasses.

I have also come across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023002/can-google-gdk-glass-development-kit-used-with-vuzix-glasses) ,but answer was posted a year before.

Comment: Can Vuzix M100 smart glasses work with WebRTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much reserch and browsing I found out that wikitude SDK can be used for developing applications that can run on both google glass and Vuzix M100 smart glasses.For details check out the documnets listed below :

- http://www.wikitude.com/documentation/
- http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/epson